# Are base class objects implicitly added to derived classes?

Tags: c++

I have just read about *subobjects* in the Standard saying this:

> A subobject can be a member subobject (9.2), a base
>   class subobject (Clause 10), or an array element.

I have encountered a lot of situations when reading about C++ where subojects were mentioned without even having a subobject(explicitly defined) in the derived class.

But does this mean that whenever a class has a base class, the compiler implicitly adds an object of the base class type in the derived class?

Like:

```
class Base
{
};
class Derived : Base
{
};
```

So a subobject of Base has been added in Derived?

Is there something in the Standard that I should have read? I am aware of that it was a very tiny quotation though.

Update:

If we had these classes:

```
class Base
{
int anint;
float afloat;
};
class Derived : Base
{
//inherited member variables...
};
```

So in the code above, are `anint`, `afloat` subobjects of `Base`? Are `anint` and `afloat` also subobjects of `Derived`? AND is there also added a member to `Derived` that looks like `Base something`? So in the end, `Derived` has three subobjects: `anint`, `afloat` and `Base something`?

Comment: Inheritance is a "is-a" relationship. In your example the class `Derived` *is a* `Base`. Exactly how it's implemented is irrelevant, but (again with your example) all members of `Base` are also members of `Derived`.

Comment: Your example would be clearer if you added some data fields.

Comment: I think that `class Derived : Base` should be classified as *explicit* addition. And there seems to be no way to implicitly add any fields to a class except for vtable.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yea, but it was more concerning whether an object of the base class type is implicitly defined in the derived class, like if an object `Base obj;` is implemented the `Derived`'s definition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, yes. The most derived class will contain sub-objects of each class it derives from. To quote C++17 (n4659 draft), [[class.derived/3]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.derived#3):

> The *base-specifier-list* specifies the type of the base class
>   subobjects contained in an object of the derived class type.
>   [ Example:
>
> ```
> struct Base {
>   int a, b, c;
> };
> struct Derived : Base {
>   int b;
> };
> struct Derived2 : Derived {
>   int c;
> };
> ```
>
> Here, an object of class Derived2 will have a subobject of class
>   Derived which in turn will have a subobject of class Base.  — end
>   example ]

The term sub-object is used more generally because inheritance is not the only way to form aggregate types. You can add members to a class, those will be sub-objects as well. And when you form arrays, each element is a sub-object of the array as a whole.

---

To address your update to the question:

> So in the code above, are `anint`, `afloat` subobjects of `Base`?

Yes. They are members of `Base` and therefore sub-objects of it. Their memory location is laid out inside the memory of a `Base` object.

> Are `anint` and `afloat` also subobjects of `Derived`?

Yes, on account of inclusion being transitive. `Derived` contains a sub-object of `Base`.

> AND is there also added a member to `Derived` that looks like `Base` something?

There is no named member for the `Base` sub-object. There is only a chunk of memory inside a `Derived` object that has a `Base` object constructed in it.

> So in the end, Derived has three subobjects: anint, afloat and Base something?

Yes. It looks like somewhat this:

```
+----------------------+
|+--------------------+|
|| int    |   float   ||
|+--------------------+|
| Base object (unnamed)|
+----------------------+
  Derived object
```

Comment: Thanks! So, for instance, `Derived` really has a `Base obj;` implemented implicitly in its definition?

Comment: I really like your quotations, but I am still not really sure whether "subobjects" are all objects inherited from the base class that has been explicitly defined in the base class' definition AND an implicit object of the base class included in the derived class' definition.. Or only the first or the second.

Comment: @sdsadasdasd - I admit I don't understand the unclear part. The example in the standard is quite explicit. `Derived` contains a `Base` sub-object, that's a given. `Derived2` contains a `Dervied` sub-object, and then since inclusion is transitive, it also contains a `Base` sub-object that is nestled in the `Derived` sub-object. All in all `Derived2` will have room for 5 integers.

Comment: @sdsadasdasd: The biggest mistake in the `Base obj` assumption, is the assumption that the Base class sub-object has a name.

Comment: Well, thanks. However, I still do not get if it is only what is explicitly declared in the base class that is inherited to the derived class? Like I do not get, based on my code and if there was an "int a" in base, if the inherited integer would be a subobject and if an object of that class has been added to the derived class and that object is a subobject too.. I know that you stated that you did not really understand the part of the standard, but can you please take a look at this comment and try to answer it as good as you can?

Comment: @sdsadasdasd - I do understand the part of the standard in question. I stated I did not understand your confusion (or your attempt to illustrate it). Sub-object clearly means "an object that is a part of a larger object". That comes in many shapes and forms. Inheritance only embeds sub-objects of a class type. Of course this is transitive. If `a` is a sub-object of `Base` and `Base` is a sub-object of `Derived` than `a` is a sub-object of `Derived`. It's true even if it is inaccessible.

Comment: Ahhh gotcha! I have updated my question though.. Can you please take a look at the updated part? I really admire your patience with me haha :)

Comment: @sdsadasdasd - Updated my answer accordingly

Comment: Hi @StoryTeller, I really like your answer and since you seem to know your stuff, I would like to ask you these questions: So subobjects can be member subobjects, base class subobjects and array elements, but when exactly are they what? I mean, if a class inherits from a base class and that base class contains two integers(`firstint` and `secint`), would the derived class then have a "base class subobject" that is the unnamed base class object and would the members of the base class be considered "member subobjects" of both the base class where they originated and in the derived class?

Comment: Also, if the members of the base class are inherited in the derived class by being inside the "base class subobject"(if that is what it is called) which is what I understand by the memory layout that you illustrated in your answer, are those members of the base class inherited INDIRECTLY to the derived class because i mean they are still inside the base class subobject? Regarding whether things are base class subobjects, for example, the unnamed subobject of the base class is a MEMBER of the derived class but still it is a base class.. I really appreciate your time!

Comment: @FacPam - Posted this much earlier, but only now realized you may not have been notified https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153192/room-for-storyteller-and-fac-pam

Comment: @StoryTeller Yea, I did not. Anyway, I have looked at your very nice answers and have asked some question regarding what you said since it is still not all clear to me, but we are getting there. Please take a look, I really appreciate this!

Answer (score 1):

> But does this mean that whenever a class has a base class, the compiler implicitly adds an object of the base class type in the derived class?

Yes. That is what being a derived class is, along with having access to the protected members of that base sub object, and being implicitly convertible to that base sub object.